# Square is to rectangle as cube is to ...?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the word I'm looking for? A shape that has 6 sides where every side has a 90 degree edge to the neighbor side.

Not necessarily a cube though, because a cube also has the additional restraint of each edge being the same length. I'm describing a shape that doesn't have that restraint.

Comment: Did you do [any research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk01nBa8kMEIpfFGodUQg6YZWQ5RPmA%3A1591738825264&source=hp&ei=yQHgXtb4DdCejLsP_MGS8Ac&q=rectangular+solid&oq=rectangular+solid&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BQgAEIMBOggIABCSAxCLAzoICAAQgwEQiwM6CAgAELEDEIsDOgUIABCLAzoFCAAQsQNQzgNY0y5gnzNoAHAAeACAAUOIAfMHkgECMTeYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6uAEC&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiWgYOa2fXpAhVQD2MBHfygBH4Q4dUDCAk&uact=5)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about geometry.

Comment: Disagreeing with close vote: the question is indeed about geometry, but it is also about the linguistics of geometry. Fundamentally this is a question about words, not shapes

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that's not a word that's two words. A description.

Comment: Great. Apparently asking for the word of a shape is not English but off topic. This is why I hate stackexchange. Are y'all afraid of shapes??? Next time I'll include "my research" as "**I tried looking online but didn't know what to look for... Because I didn't know the word to use.**" Thanks to the people who answered in good nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuboid

A cube is a cuboid where every face is a square.

Other related words

- Hexahedron: like a cuboid, but without the constraint of all sides being at 90 degree angles
- Paralleliped: A hexahedron where every face is a parallelogram

Comment: Wikipedia indicates that this is indeed one definition of “cuboid”, but that it also has an alternative definition referring to any convex polyhedron with six quadrilateral faces.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is a single word (noun) that is also short, while a lot of the other answers are an adjective + noun.

Answer (score 4):

You can call it a **right rectangular prism.**

A rectangular prism by definition has two parallel rectangular faces, and specifying that it is a [right prism](https://www.mathwords.com/r/right_prism.htm) means that the quadrilaterals connecting those two rectangular faces will also be rectangles.

Comment: I would just call it a rectangular prism https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/rectangular-prism.html. Not sure why you got downvoted.

Comment: @Damila: It is a rectangular prism. But technically, a shape with two parallel rectangular faces and two or four lateral faces that are non-rectangular parallelograms could also be called a rectangular prism (an oblique prism, like the example on the right on [this page](https://calcworkshop.com/volume-surface-area/prism/)).

Comment: I haven’t seen an oblique prism called a rectangular prism, but I am not a math teacher and I would not be surprised if the proper name is as you say. In any case, this is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

***[Rectangular parallelepiped](https://byjus.com/maths/parallelepiped/)***
(noun)

> A rectangular parallelepiped is a three-dimensional structure whose all the six faces are in a rectangular shape and the length of the parallel edges are equal.

(byjus.com/maths)

Comment: A parallelepiped does not fit the requirement that all faces are at 90 degree angles to each other

Comment: @JonStory - If the faces are rectangular, how could they not be at 90 degrees to each other?

Comment: @JonStory Agree that *parallelepiped* does not fit the requirement, but *rectangular parallelepiped* does.

Comment: @HotLicks You see the Euclideanism inherent in the system? Help, help, I'm being dehyperbolized!

Comment: @choster - Euclid was warped!

Comment: @HotLicks you may also notice that the "Rectangular" was edited in after my comment. At the time of the comment, the answer only said "Parallelepiped". The word rectangular appears to have been added in response to my comment

Answer (score -2):

[hexahedron](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/hexahedron): a solid body of six sides or faces.

All cubes are hexahedrons, but not all hexahedrons are cubes.

Comment: A hexahedron does not require that every side has a 90 degree angle to each other side: a parallelepiped, for example, has parallelograms on two sides and would therefore be a haxahedron without fitting OP's restraints. All cubes are cuboids, all cuboids are hexahedrons, but not all hexahedrons are cuboids (which is the word OP actually wants)